# If my implementation or header file imports non-ARC code, does that mean this file is non-ARC as well?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

For example if I use a big open source library which isn't ARC, does that mean anywhere where I import that library I have to set the `-fno-objc-arc` compiler flag? Or is it enough to just set the `-fno-objc-arc` on the relevant non-ARC library files only?

Answer (score 1):

Just the library files, not the importing files.

Comment: So if I wanted to modify those library files, of course I'd still have  to use -retain -release -autorelease -etc, right?

Answer (score 1):

is enough to just put it in the relevant file